# Openfire Plugin compilation issue

Tags: java, android, plugins, openfire

I'm trying to compile openfire in eclipse that is work fine.After i need to compile plugin.I pass reference of openfire.

Reference of this video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KlMaBplFbuQ

and my structure of openfire check in below image.

I got issue when i tried to build with ant.It ask me go to src and tool folder but i put that outside directory.Now i'm trying to build with main directory but still got exception.

[image]

I'm not able to give accurate path of main directory while building tool folder as well. This is problem.

Somebody have idea about this issue please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to build or compile plugin from eclipse.If you use **ant-build** for build openfire then it work fine.
Just you make sure, Ant is installed and configure proper path in your system.

Go to your downloaded openfire and paste your plugin under openfire/src/plugin folder.

Go command line, you can pass command

**ant -f build/build.xml clean openfire plugins**

or build specific plugin you can pass

**ant -f build/build.xml clean openfire plugin -Dplugin=nameofyourplugin**

after building you can check your plugin in this path.

**\openfire\target\openfire\plugins**

Thanks hope this will help you.