# Create jar file from openfire plugin

Tags: java, plugins, compilation, xmpp, openfire

I need to customize openfire plugin and i have made one plugin for openfire but no idea how to compile.I have followed many tutorial but not working.

Here is one [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KlMaBplFbuQ) for compile openfire but got 505 error.

I have followed official tutorial but not able to compile.

```
build\build.xml:238: Must use JDK 1.5.x or higher to build Openfire
```

got this exception.

Not get idea how can i make jar file with compilation or without.If with, I tried with ant as well but there is some problem.

I'm stack here in openfire problem and compilation of plugin. If anybody have idea about this problem please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the output of `javac -version` (if you run it in a terminal)? Why don't you create the .jar using an IDE (E.g.: Eclipse): right click > Export > Export... ?

Comment: @engineer i'm using eclipse and trying to compile from eclipse. pls check my question this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36332971/openfire-plugin-compilation-issue

Comment: yes i know this way but this is not working. May be openfire plugin need to build from ant as i read from docus but that giving me exception.

Comment: In Eclipse, go to Window > Preferences > Java > Compiler and write here the version from your "Compiler compliance level"

Comment: i used 1.8 compiler version

Comment: i'm not sure but may be problem in buidlfile when i setup ant compilation.check out my other question i have posted screenshot

Comment: i have exproted and upload plugin but not showing in openfire admin section.

Comment: Post the line 238 from build.xml.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107940/discussion-between-nitin-sood-and-engineer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to build or compile plugin from eclipse.If you use ant-build for build openfire then it work fine. Just you make sure, Ant is installed and configure proper path in your system.

Go to your downloaded openfire and paste your plugin under openfire/src/plugin folder.

Go command line, you can pass command

**ant -f build/build.xml clean openfire plugins**

or build specific plugin you can pass

**ant -f build/build.xml clean openfire plugin -Dplugin=nameofyourplugin**

after building you can check your plugin in this path.

**\openfire\target\openfire\plugins**

Thanks hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

According to our extended discussion from chat, you added the following part:

```
<condition property="java.not.ok" value="true"> 
    <not> 
        <or> 
            <contains string="${ant.java.version}" substring="1.5"/> 
            <contains string="${ant.java.version}" substring="1.6"/> 
            <contains string="${ant.java.version}" substring="1.7"/> 
        </or> 
    </not> 
</condition>
```

You also need to **add the following line** after those 3 similar lines:

```
            <contains string="${ant.java.version}" substring="1.8"/>
```

because you are using Java 8 (according to your comment related to compiler version). Otherwise, this condition will be evaluated to true (`java.not.ok=true`) and this will activate the following line:

```
<fail if="java.not.ok" message="Must use JDK 1.5.x or higher to build Openfire"/>
```