# Openfire CallbackOnOffline plugin not triggered [plugin.callback_on_offline.url] URL for offline user

Tags: xmpp, openfire, smack

Openfire server version 4.2.3 and I've used CallbackOnOffline 1.2.1-SNAPSHOT which downloaded from GitHub and generated jar file [mvn package command] and upload it via Openfire admin console[I've installed 1.2.0 version from admin console and got the same error].
Here is the error log from the server.

```
2018.10.30 09:09:11 org.jivesoftware.openfire.interceptor.InterceptorManager - Error in interceptor: com.fotsum.CallbackOnOffline@7ceec048 while intercepting: 
<message id="v12r3-44" to="user_55@18.215.249.194" from="user_70@18.215.249.194/Spark 2.6.3" type="chat">
  <body>this is log test</body>
  <thread>55H5xR</thread>
  <x xmlns="jabber:x:event">
    <offline/>
    <composing/>
  </x>
</message>
java.lang.IllegalStateException: InjectionManagerFactory not found.
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.lambda$lookupInjectionManagerFactory$0(Injections.java:98)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:290)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.lookupInjectionManagerFactory(Injections.java:98)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.createInjectionManager(Injections.java:68)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig$State.initRuntime(ClientConfig.java:432)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.collection.Values$LazyValueImpl.get(Values.java:341)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig.getRuntime(ClientConfig.java:826)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.getConfiguration(ClientRequest.java:285)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.validateHttpMethodAndEntity(JerseyInvocation.java:143)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.<init>(JerseyInvocation.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.<init>(JerseyInvocation.java:108)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.<init>(JerseyInvocation.java:99)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$AsyncInvoker.method(JerseyInvocation.java:713)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$AsyncInvoker.post(JerseyInvocation.java:591)
    at com.fotsum.CallbackOnOffline.interceptPacket(CallbackOnOffline.java:130)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.interceptor.InterceptorManager.invokeInterceptors(InterceptorManager.java:268)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.interceptor.InterceptorManager.invokeInterceptors(InterceptorManager.java:230)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.MessageRouter.route(MessageRouter.java:172)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.spi.PacketRouterImpl.route(PacketRouterImpl.java:79)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.net.StanzaHandler.processMessage(StanzaHandler.java:384)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.net.ClientStanzaHandler.processMessage(ClientStanzaHandler.java:109)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.net.StanzaHandler.process(StanzaHandler.java:238)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.net.StanzaHandler.process(StanzaHandler.java:201)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.nio.ConnectionHandler.messageReceived(ConnectionHandler.java:177)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$TailFilter.messageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:690)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextMessageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:417)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$1200(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:47)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.messageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:765)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.IoFilterAdapter.messageReceived(IoFilterAdapter.java:109)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.plugin.RawPrintFilter.messageReceived(RawPrintFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextMessageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:417)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$1200(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:47)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.messageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:765)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.IoFilterAdapter.messageReceived(IoFilterAdapter.java:109)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextMessageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:417)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$1200(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:47)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.messageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:765)
    at org.apache.mina.filter.codec.ProtocolCodecFilter$ProtocolDecoderOutputImpl.flush(ProtocolCodecFilter.java:407)
    at org.apache.mina.filter.codec.ProtocolCodecFilter.messageReceived(ProtocolCodecFilter.java:236)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextMessageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:417)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$1200(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:47)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.messageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:765)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.IoFilterEvent.fire(IoFilterEvent.java:74)
    at org.apache.mina.core.session.IoEvent.run(IoEvent.java:63)
    at org.apache.mina.filter.executor.OrderedThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(OrderedThreadPoolExecutor.java:769)
    at org.apache.mina.filter.executor.OrderedThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTasks(OrderedThreadPoolExecutor.java:761)
    at org.apache.mina.filter.executor.OrderedThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(OrderedThreadPoolExecutor.java:703)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

also debug log url: https://files.fm/u/z8x4rmsm

Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got the solution. We've to build the plugin entirely from scratch. You can get the latest debug plugin jar from this link: https://github.com/swaponsust/CallbackOnOffline

Comment: Hi @Swapon, can you describe how to build this plugin? I have changed some lines of code but I don't know how to build the plugin for openfire. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Fuyuba It was built by another developer from Freelancer.com profile link: https://www.freelancer.com.bd/u/Pro4Magento

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem for 1 month.there is a problem in `.jar` file.here is the tricky part :
you should download the source file and compile it your self using `ants` and export a `.jar` plugin and upload it to openfire server.after that `CallBackOnOffline` will works.
here is the link for compiling openfire plugins:
[compile openfire plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36353231/create-jar-file-from-openfire-plugin)

Comment: Hi Andesta,
Thanks for your comment. 

I did exactly what you've suggested at that link but unfortunately got the below-error. I've tried with plugin 1.2.0 and 1.2.1 but not succeed. Do you've any working plugin jar to test it? 

error link: https://codeshare.io/aYrVQQ